# Javascript lastModified date

Tags: javascript

I have webpages on my local hard drive that use Javascript to get the lastModified date of a non-html file and display newer entries.  However, it does not work with other computers in my homegroup.  I am VERY new to Javascript and know very little. In researching found it is prob. due to security settings. Is there a relatively easy way to code so that others in my homegroup can see this? (or even a link to help me figure this out?)  My JavaScript code accesses the lastModified date of a file and adds an "updated" .gif next to the list entry.  All PC's in the homegroup are using windows 7 & firefox 18.  Thanks in advance!  (I will provide the code if needed...)

Comment: XML is just plain text and does not execute in any way, so it is unclear what you want to do. I think you need to refine your question, post examples and narrow down what you want to do.

Comment: More precisely: XML is pure syntax. There are many markup languages implemented in XML, representing different kinds of documents, data, and (in some cases) programs. But if you're just saying XML in general, then you're talking about raw data, and you would not be using XML to get the lastModified date of anything. I'm presuming that what you really have is a pure Javascript issue, and I'm going to reset the tags and description appropriately.